# Location of grafana.ini file in windows system

Tags: config, grafana, grafana-alerts

I am working with **Grafana V10.1.5** running on windows PC.

I am trying to locate **grafana.ini file in windows PC** but its no where to be found. The installed location of grafana in my PC is **"C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana"** though same thing can be found in linux PC without any hassle.

Although I have found two **".ini" file**, one by the name **"default.ini"** other by the name **"sample.ini"**. Both these files are located at **"C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\conf"**.

[image: .ini files]

**Is one of these two is "grafana.ini" file?** If i want to configure grafana for "smtp", which one of these i should choose because content of both files is exactly the same except "sample.ini" have every thing commented out while "default.ini" have everything uncommented?

Comment: You could try searching the file using this tool https://www.voidtools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `grafana.ini` on windows. There might be `custom.ini`, that assumes the same role as `grafana.ini` on *nix versions, but only if **you** created it.

Please reference [official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/installation/windows/) on matters of installing on Windows.

> Open the `conf` directory and copy `sample.ini` to `custom.ini`.
>
> > **Note:** You should edit `custom.ini`, never `defaults.ini`.
>
> `;` is the comment character in ini files.